# Gold Plating on Glass?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, metal, equipment, glass, noble-metals

I am considering labware options to handle NaOH solutions at ~150 °C. One appealing idea would be to coat my current glassware with gold. I've read different sources mentioning the possibility without further detail.

The most detailed description of a process for this is [INSTRUCTIONS FOR GOLD PLATING ON GLASS](http://www.peacocklabs.com/docs/instructions/Gold-Plating-on-Glass-Instructions.pdf) by Peacock Laboratories, Inc who sells (or used to sell) products for doing so. Unfortunately, this says little as to the chemical mechanisms involved.

Would anyone guess what chemicals are being used in this process and know how to explain the mechanisms at hand, and perhaps describe properties to expect from the result?

Can I expect impermeability from the coating or at least a significantly reduced glass surface exposure to hydroxides? What is the best resistance to expect vs routine cleaning of glassware that would be coated with such a method? Can I expect it to not dissociate upon heat shocks that borosilicate glass can handle? Would there be any chemicals to avoid with such a coating, other than the few that would be expected to react with / dissolve gold metal?

Comment: I checked that well known auction site and found lots of titanium cups and such available. Apparently, campers buy titanium bowls, cups, etc. and the cost is lower than I expected. Maybe worthwhile to buy a titanium cup and check it out.

Comment: @EdV Thanks for the tip! Using titanium recipients is a possibility I didn't think about. I may have read somewhere that some titanium compounds are amphoteric though. Do you know if NaOH could dissolve traces of it from the cups? The prospect of being able to use my current glassware is appealing because the only work would be the coating part. But if titanium doesn't react I could try to recreate that equipment out of it (I really only need a cup to bring NaOH to high temperature and then a filtration apparatus). Another advantage of titanium would be not having to worry about thermal shocks

Comment: @EdV I'm not sure what this translates into in the context of high temperature NaOH for a few dozen minutes, but I found the following statement in a paper:

Comment: "Titanium is generally very resistant alkaline media including solutions of sodium hydroxide, potassium hydroxide. calcium hydroxide and ammonium hydroxide. In concentrations of up to approximately 70c for example, titanium exhibits corrosic rates of less than or equal to 5 mpy [(0.12 mm/yr) Table 18.] Near nil corrosion rate are exhibited in boiling calcium hydroxide, magnesium hydroxide, and ammonium hydroxide solutions up to saturation. ...

Comment: ... 
Despite low corrosion rates in alkali solutions, hydrogen pickup and possible embrittlement of titanium can occur at temperatures above 170°F (77°C) when solution pH is greater than or equal to 12" Source: https://www.nrc.gov/docs/ML9932/ML993210187.pdf

Comment: I would try a titanium cup, in any event. Also, I just checked and that same auction site lists lots of graphite and SiC crucibles, for not much money. No problem with the temperature, but only you can decide about your NaOH purity requirements.

Comment: @EdV Could SiC react with NaOH at high temperature in the presence of O2 (producing sodium carbonate and a sodium silicate)? As for my purity requirements: Should I contaminate the NaOH I would much rather have gold than titanium inside (though I'd also rather have 1-3ppm of titanium and <0.3 ppm of many other elements).

Comment: I have no idea if SiC reacts at high temperature with NaOH in the presence of oxygen. But the larger issue is this: you would prefer to have low (or sub) ppm contamination and that means analytical testing somewhere down the road. As an analytical chemist, I can tell you this is where it can start to get expensive: nobody does pro bono trace analysis and nobody wants to possibly contaminate their expensive hyphenated instrument with unsuspected contaminants in a sample from the wild. So, good luck with whatever you decide to do!

Comment: How about Sterling silver (92.5% Ag, 7.5% Cu) cups? Lots available fairly inexpensive at that auction site. You could buy a small cup (“child’s cup”) and test it very easily. As well, pure silver is very easily purchased, thanks to all the silver bullion collectors, and could be tested with the NaOH.

Comment: @EdV It might be the way to go, though I'm less inspired by copper and the other stuff in there than by silver itself (because the compounds of silver have quite consistently very low solubility). I could get pure silver but then I'd have to get into the absolute mess of casting what I need out of it (though even if I buy sterling silver I'll have to make a filtration apparatus out of it, and most probably plate it with gold to be on the safe side).

Comment: Maybe sterling silver > pure silver plating > gold plating. I know that silver slowly diffuses into gold but I don't know if copper and small amounts of heavy metals from the sterling silver could diffuse through the plated pure silver layer.

Comment: >I am considering labware options to handle NaOH solutions at ~150°C. || AFAIK, Iron is stable in molten NaOH.

Comment: Try gold fuming maybe? could take quite a bit to get a consistent layer, it's commonly used in the artistic side of THC consumption but may be worth exploring. good luck!

Comment: @Stoner_Scientist. Thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gold plating glass could probably be 99.99% complete. It would make a nice mirror and would probably stay unoxidized for a long time.

However, if I wanted to remove the gold, I think I would rinse the glass with HF solution, or perhaps NaOH solution, either of which would find those teeny tiny gaps and undercut the whole gold plate.

I don't think there would be any strong chemical bonding, and no mechanical strength to a gold film. Glass is just a reactive substrate, and protecting it would require a finite thickness, with mechanical strength.

An example of plating not working well is chromium plating (although it can be done very well, it requires much attention to detail). Automobile bumpers used to be chrome plated, but developed rust spots after a few years because of porosity in the chromium film. I believe nickel plating to reduce corrosion tendency (but Ni is not shiny enough) followed by chrome plating works reasonably well. But then there is hexavalent chromium toxicity... So now we just paint the bumpers or make them out of plastic.

Perhaps you could coat the glass with teflon or polypropylene.

Comment: I see that polypropylene melts at 160C, and Teflon is only good up to 260C, so I don't think either of those would work for the application described...?

Comment: Your second sentence pretty much says it all. And stirring anything in a gold-plated beaker or flask, especially something moderately viscous, would be problem.

Comment: @JamesGaidis: Thank you for your answer! I know that is some cases gold compounds (oxides?) can act amphoterically but I'm not sure it would apply here, so if I understand right, the way NaOH would remove the gold layer would be by gradually dissolving the glass underneath it, not interacting with the gold itself in any way? Could I prevent this by coating a thicker layer and somehow try to make it more uniform, maybe by baking the glassware between coating "passes"?

Comment: @EdV: Would stirring be a problem because of the friction with the coating layer?

Comment: Pure gold is very soft and it is the most malleable metal, so it would be very easy to scratch, which would then expose the glass substrate. Therefore, stirring becomes a bit problematic: no stir bars, no boiling chips, no glass rod and so on. I think the gold layer would have to be unreasonably thick in order to be effective. But a rest piece, e.g., a gold coated microscope slide, or test tube, could be tried.

Comment: @EdV: The rest piece is a very smart idea. All I'd need to use (which was prospectively to be in contact with the to-be-coated glass walls) is a very large magnetic stirring rod out of PTFE which I think is softer than metallic gold or a smaller magnetic rod out of glass (which I'd then also coat). It would be smart to have distinctive "wear" pieces where friction is needed (e.g. the magnetic glass rod and a resting plate/disk out of glass), as I could re-coat them separately and give them thicker coating.

Comment: The glass rod and resting disk would wear out on each other but the vessels and filtering apparatus which don't require being subjected to much friction would stay unaffected. If PTFE can be used, and if it is indeed softer than the gold coating, then the combination of a soft material vs slightly less soft one might be preferable to having friction between two components of the same material and with the same coating. I'm not exactly sure what that implies but PTFE has a glass temperature at 114.85 °C though, which may affect the suitability of the stirring rod.

Comment: As for the resting plate for the stirring rod, I could even stretch a metallic gold piece to fit that purpose, which would leave the stirring rod as the only "wear" part to be re-coated each time (assuming the Au-coated glass magnetic rod is the best option).

Comment: Two things: 1) "rest" was actually a typo for "test". Sorry! 2) If a PTFE stirring bar is OK at the specified temperature and putative NaOH concentration, why not use PTFE beakers? I currently have 8 brand new Teflon® beakers left from the dozen I purchased in 1987. Send me an e-mail (you can find my e-mail address pretty easily) and I will send you a beaker, gratis. Then test it! Like Yogi Berra might have said: "In theory, theory and practice are the same. In practice, they aren't."

Comment: One more thing: I have some titanium disks, about 2 inch diameter, so I will be happy to send along a few, if you want to test how they hold up to the NaOH. Just let me know.

Comment: @EdV That's a very generous offer, and I thank you for it! If possible I would like to avoid abusing your generosity, so I'll first try to determine if that is the best option. I've been thinking for instance about silver as an option also. I think it's amphoteric like gold and titanium in some circumstances, but I'm not sure if it means NaOH could attack the metallic form. The advantage over teflon would be much higher heat resistance, and the advantage over titanium and pyrex is that it forms much less soluble salts which are easier to get rid of later in the process.

Comment: I suspect that even if silver does react with NaOH, it could do so much slower than glass/pyrex, which would also make for a more resistant Au gold layer on it compared to glass (if I understood correctly that NaOH would remove the gold layer by reacting not with gold directly but with the glass underneath). Ag diffuses in Au very slowly but if it doesn't react much with NaOH that's fine. Now the bad side is I'd have to work with silver metal and build a filtering apparatus out of it (but probably much easier to work with than titanium)

Comment: @Hans - Just a safety related concern with James' answer - The recommendation of using HF to remove the gold if needed is, in my opinion, excessive and a generally unsafe recommendation to make. I would urge y'all to consider using [Aqua Regia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aqua_regia) to remove the gold directly. I only recommend this as HF is scary - like [disolves your bones when inhaled](https://ehs.unc.edu/files/2015/09/hydrofluoricacid.pdf) kind of scary. Stay safe out there, folks.

Comment: Aqua regia is great for gold - HF was just an acid to dissolve glass because it wasn't 100.00% protected. Of course, aqua regia ain't all fun and games either!

Comment: @TaylorScott Tanks for the safety recommendation!

Comment: I awarded the bounty to this answer. Not that it is a complete answer to the question but it's the only formal answer and contains valuable information. I've also noticed that James frequently makes nice answers to people's questions in general.

Comment: How do you coat something with teflon? Are there teflon spray cans?

Comment: @Juan Perez: spray-on Teflon powder is available online. Chemical application of Teflon to metal is a commercial process - you could look it up.